# insert into table

Tags: plsql

[image: Есть таблица с наименованием полей и значении]

как из этой таблицы вставить данные в таблицу с соответсвующими полями, чтобы было вот так:

[image]

Comment: Выбирай один столбец

Comment: Я в оракле новичок, может примерчик покажете как это сделать?!

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into table1(schet_izv,period,res)
select max(decode(param_title,'SCHET_IZV',param_value,NULL)),
       max(decode(param_title,'PERIOD',param_value,NULL)),
       max(decode(param_title,'RES',param_value,NULL))
  from table2
```

Для Oracle 11g и выше:

```
insert into table1(schet_izv,period,res)
select *
  from (select param_title, param_value
          from table2)
 pivot (max(param_value)
         for param_title in('SCHET_IZV','PERIOD','RES')
       )
```

Comment: а как циклом можно сделать без явного указания названия полей?

Comment: @AskarOffAskat SQL не может ничего делать без названия полей. Вам для начала надо же создать таблицу с подходящими полями. тут уже нужны имена. потом циклом - это 3 обращения к одной и той же записи, причем на update  изменением ее длины. При этом образуются chained записи, которые гробят всю производительность при последующей работой  с такой таблицей. В общем такой изврат   можно изобразить, создавая запросы динамически, но оно того не стоит. Раз понадобилось - значит неправильная постановка задачи или задача не для реляционной БД.

Comment: @AskarOffAskat Вы можете попробовать извлечь все поля для пивот как то так:
`select listagg('''' || param_titel || '''' || ' as ' || param_titel, ', ') within group (order by param_titel) pivot_titels from table2`
и подсунуть это в IN () динамически. Как заметил Mike - стоит ли это делать?